# What is connection between Euler graphs, bipartite graphs and having even number of vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, eulerian-path

Prove or disprove:

> 1. If $G$ is an Euler graph with even number of vertices then it's bipartite.
> 2. If $G$ is an Euler and bipartite graph then the number of its vertices is even.

The second claim is false I think because for example for a graph of $7$ vertices we can construct Euler circuit and it can be a bipartite graph. This is the illustration:

[image]

Regarding the second claim because it's an Euler graph then the degree of every vertex is even. But I don't see how to use this fact to prove that it is/is not a bipartite graph.